# Uploading a simple CSV file to a controller

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, hash

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to my controller and access the data within.

Here's the code for the Controller:

```
class DatabaseImporterController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def import
    # Receive the uploaded CSV file and import to the database.
    csv_file = params[:csv_file]
    logger.debug  { csv_file.inspect }
    #CSV.foreach("parse.csv") do |row|

    #end
    render :template => "database_importer/index"
  end
end
```

And the ouput of `logger.debug`:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
 "authenticity_token"=>"Z4+XlmrcH+8JPL6Yq52ymVOMfiGEI9mN8LuoxoBLp8M=", 
 "csv_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007feca81b3fb8 @original_filename="Install-Linux-tar.txt", @content_type="text/plain", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"csv_file\"; filename=\"Install-Linux-tar.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20121229-10294-1ngf634>>, 
 "commit"=>"Import CSV Car Database", 
 "controller"=>"database_importer", 
 "action"=>"import"}
```

Accoding to the documentation on the official [Ruby on Rails page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html):

> The object in the params hash is an instance of a subclass of IO. Depending on the size of the uploaded file it may in fact be a StringIO or **an instance of File backed by a temporary file.**

As I understand it, the uploaded file is somewhere in my disc (in my Heroku instance) and I can access it temporarily.

How can I access the file? I've tried the following and I get and error message:

```
csv_file = params[:csv_file][:tempfile] # This is how I try to get the file page of the temporary file.

undefined method `[]' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fecb02103c8>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call `tempfile`, not `[:tempfile]`:

```
params[:csv_file].tempfile
```

You can see all the methods available in the [docs for `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html).

Comment: I've changed the line to `csv_file = params[:csv_file].tempfile` and the `logger.debug` still displays the same hash. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Serg It cannot be (for one, because `params[:csv_file].tempfile` isn’t a hash, but also because it doesn’t know anything about your params). Verify that you’re printing the correct thing.